# How to capture a remote website using Java Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

can anyone tell me how I can capture a webpage using Java Selenium? With an example....

Comment: What do you mean by "capture and webpage", you could only capture HTTP requests, and so on, but not a webpage.

Comment: i mean the screen short using selenium

Answer (score 2):

See here: [Capturing screenshots from remote Selenium RC](http://seleniumexamples.com/blog/examples/capturing-screenshots-from-remote-selenium-rc/).

In essence:

"To solve this you can use the captureScreenshotToString and captureEntirePageScreenshotToString commands, which return a Base64 encoded String of the screenshot, which you can then decode and save to disk on your testrunner machine."

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for. But try to be mores specific if it is not.

> captureEntirePageScreenshot (
>   filename,kwargs )
>       Saves the entire contents of the current window canvas to a PNG file.
>   Contrast this with the
>   captureScreenshot command, which
>   captures the contents of the OS
>   viewport (i.e. whatever is currently
>   being displayed on the monitor), and
>   is implemented in the RC only.
>   Currently this only works in Firefox
>   when running in chrome mode, and in IE
>   non-HTA using the EXPERIMENTAL
>   "Snapsie" utility. The Firefox
>   implementation is mostly borrowed from
>   the Screengrab! Firefox extension.
>   Please see http://www.screengrab.org
>   and http://snapsie.sourceforge.net/
>   for details.
>
> ```
> Arguments:
>
>     * filename - the path to the file to persist the screenshot as. No
> ```
>
> filename extension will be appended by
>   default. Directories will not be
>   created if they do not exist, and an
>   exception will be thrown, possibly by
>   native code.
>           * kwargs - a kwargs string that modifies the way the screenshot
>   is captured. Example:
>   "background=#CCFFDD" . Currently valid
>   options:
>
> ```
>       background
>           the background CSS for the HTML document. This may be useful
> ```
>
> to set for capturing screenshots of
>   less-than-ideal layouts, for example
>   where absolute positioning causes the
>   calculation of the canvas dimension to
>   fail and a black background is exposed
>   (possibly obscuring black text).

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void getSnapShot(WebDriver driver, String event) {
     {
        try {
            File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
            BufferedImage originalImage = ImageIO.read(scrFile);
            //int type = originalImage.getType() == 0 ? BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB : originalImage.getType();
            BufferedImage resizedImage = CommonUtilities.resizeImage(originalImage, IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH);
            ImageIO.write(resizedImage, "jpg", new File(path + "/"+ testCaseId + "/img/" + index + ".jpg"));
            Image jpeg = Image.getInstance(path + "/" + testCaseId + "/img/"+ index + ".jpg");
            jpeg.setAlignment(Image.MIDDLE);

            ++index;
        } catch (Exception  e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to use PhantomJS driver for taking screenshots.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //PhantomJS headless driver
        File file = new File("D:\\Webdriver\\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\\bin\\phantomjs.exe");
        System.setProperty("phantomjs.binary.path", file.getAbsolutePath());
        WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver();

        //Set Size here
        driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1600,900));

        //To wait until the element get visible or invisible.
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 25);

        //To access url.
        driver.get("https://www.google.co.in");

        //For wait until the element get visible.
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("lst-ib")));

        File shot=((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        FileUtils.copyFile(shot, new File("D:\\Webdriver\\Capture.jpg"));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It takes full page screenshot of chrome webpage.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "F:\\chromedriver.exe"); 

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);   
String baseUrl = "https://www.google.co.in";

driver.get(baseUrl);        
String fullscreen =Keys.chord(Keys.F11);
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(fullscreen);

TakesScreenshot scrShot =((TakesScreenshot)driver);  
File SrcFile=scrShot.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);   
File DestFile=new File("F://test.png");  
FileUtils.copyFile(SrcFile, DestFile);   
driver.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a lot of answers explaining screenshots, but just incase you are asking how to get the entire source of the page use the following method:

```
  String pageSource = driver.getPageSource();
```

[Here is a runnable example.](https://mx1.maxtaf.com/cases/4e5bc8b7-e5b1-4579-ae77-ec712f872bd7?projectId=bugtestproject2)